# How to export the result of print into a csv file in Python?

Tags: python, csv, networkx

How to export the result of following code into a csv file in python?

```
print(['%s %0.2f'%(node,centrality[node]) for node in centrality])
```

The result looks like this:

```
['faef 0.37', 'efef 0.60', 'vsav 0.60', 'fadf 0.37']
```

And I want it to be like this in a file.csv:

```
faef,0.37
efef,0.60
vsav,0.60
fadf,0.37
```

Thx ahead! I am using python 2.7 in Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv    
data = ['faef 0.37', 'efef 0.60', 'vsav 0.60', 'fadf 0.37']

with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    complete_data = []
    for d in data:
       data_to_write = d.split(" ")
       complete_data.append(data_to_write)
    a.writerows(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

result = ['faef 0.37', 'efef 0.60', 'vsav 0.60', 'fadf 0.37']    
with open('path/to/file', 'w') as outfilehandle:
    outfile = csv.writer(outfilehandle, delimiter=',')
    outfile.writelines([s.split() for s in result])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

data = ['faef 0.37', 'efef 0.60', 'vsav 0.60', 'fadf 0.37']
with open('test.csv', 'w') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    for x in data:
        k, v = x.split(' ')
        writer.writerow([k, v])
```

**OUTPUT file**

```
faef,0.37
efef,0.60
vsav,0.60
fadf,0.37
```